# Webbrowser.navigate fails to login the first time

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

i am using this code.

`

```
       string username = "username";
        string password = "pass";
        string login = "login";
        string _urlLogin = "http:xxxxxxx";
        Uri _uriLogin = new Uri(_urlLogin);
        string _postData = "userName=" + username + "&pwd=" + password + "&loginTrue=" + login;
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_postData);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(_uriLogin, data, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`
```

the first time i run it the site tells me an 11000 error occured but if i run it again it logs in just fine. Anyone knows why this happens and how i can fix it?

Comment: is it the website returning the error or the webBrowser control?

Answer (score 0):

If the website is returning an error message then you will need to figure out what that error means. Alternatively you could sniff the traffic on the wire using [Fiddler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx) and compare the 1st/2nd attempts against each-other and against a desktop web browser to see what differences there are. It may be a cookie or HTTP header issue that the web browser control is automatically adding to the second attempt.